# web google auth doesn't work in facebook browser and messenger

Tags: facebook, google-oauth, facebook-messenger, facebook-browser

All links posted via facebook or sent via messenger usually opens in facebook browser, it just WebView component.
Google auth for web doesn’t work in facebook browser - endless spinner on ios and android. Other mobile and desktop browsers works well. It doesn't work on official google documentation.

You can reproduce it on pinterest.com site:

1. post pinterest.com link somewhere in facebook(on the wall or send it via messenger)
2. click on this link from facebook app
3. try to login via google

Actual behaviour - endless spinner
Expected result - user able to login

Any idea why it happening and how to fix it? It doesn't work on almost all sites I've checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the webview that the devs from those apps have chosen to use are not compatible with Google OAuth.
Check out this link for example where it explains that Google is going to block such embedded browsers from using the signin on their OAuth system.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html#comment-form

This is a somewhat recent post talking about the subject. If you research more about the relation of embedded browsers and the compatibility list on the link above, you may find your answer